# Random access to n observations

Tags: sas

Say I have a set of 50 variables and 50 observations.

Is it possible to access 100 random "cells" and change their values?

It would be great if I hadn't had to use SQL for this.

Comment: 1. Yes, 2. I don't know what the question is. Please expand on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Reeza I've deleted the second question because the concept didn't any make sense. Can you elaborate on the former?

Comment: You need to explain what you want to do in more detail, and what you've tried. Also, do you have SAS/IML.

Comment: @Reeza Sorry, I barely know what SAS/IML is. I'd like to know if there's a solution using `data`, `set` statements (Base SAS?). I want to set the value of 100 randomly chosen cells to `.` (the original set doesn't have any missing values).

Comment: Is it important to set exactly 100 values to missing or is it okay to give each value a 4% chance of being set to missing (so could have end up with less than 100 or more than 100)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sampling rate is 0.04 - 4% of records will be set to missing. I'm assuming you have variables that are all the same type and can be listed in an array. Even so, there are ways around that. Another option is to flip your data to a wide structure, use Proc SurveySelect to select 100 random values and set to missing.
The code below uses only BASE SAS techniques.

```
/*Generate sample data*/
data sample;
array var(50) var1-var50;
do i=1 to 50;
    do j=1 to 50;
        var(j)=rand('normal', 25, 4);
        end;
    output;
end;

drop i j;
run;

*randomly assign to missing;
data sample_missing;
    call streaminit(123); *ensure reproducible 100 records;
    set sample;
    array var(50) var1-var50;
    rate=100/(50*50); *based on your question;

    retain num_miss 0;
    do i=1 to 50;

    if rand('bernoulli', rate) = 1 and num_miss < 100 then do;
        var(i)=.;
        num_miss+1;
    end;

    end;
run;

/*Check the values and code*/   
data check;
set sample_missing end=eof;
retain nmiss_cum;
nmiss_row = nmiss(of var1--var50);
nmiss_cum+nmiss_row;

/*if you only want to see the total number missing for checks uncomment the next two lines*/
**if eof then output;

 * *keep nmiss_cum;
run;
```

Comment: I was hoping it would be possible to change exactly 100 values (and without transforming the data to one dimension) but it seems that your answer is the best one can do. Thanks.

Comment: For that seed, yes. Also, I think you meant to pass `rate` variable to `rand()` if I understand correctly.

Comment: @lavsprat You're correct - different seeds don't always generate 100.  There are other ways to keep it in a data step but transposing is probably the easiest.

Comment: @lavsprat other approach would be to think of your data as 2500 cells. Select 100 random numbers between 1 and 2500. Then recode those cells to missing. If that approach sounds useful, I could add it.

Comment: @Quentin Please, do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want exactly 100 missing values, a straight-forward brute force method would be to think of your data as 2500 cells.  Generate a list of 100 random numbers between 1 and 2500.  Then set those cells to missing.  Something like below:

```
data sample;
  array x(50);
  do i=1 to 50;
    do j=1 to 50;
      x(j)=rand('normal', 25, 4);
    end;
    output;
  end;

  drop i j;
run;

**Generate list of 100 random numbers (there are doubtless better ways : );
data cellno;
  do cellno=1 to 2500;
    ran=ranuni(3);
    output;
  end;
run;
proc sql outobs=100 noprint;
  select cellno into :celllist separated by " "
  from cellno
  order by ran
  ;
run;

%put &celllist;

*Use that list to recode 100 cells to null;
data want; 
  set sample;
  array x(50);
  do i=1 to 50;
    if (_n_-1)*50+i IN (&celllist) then
      call missing(x{i});
  end;
  drop i;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably simplest to apply the K/N random sample technique to this problem. Only difference is that instead on just selection over observations you select over the individual elements in the variable array.

```
%let seed=12345;
%let varlist=X1-X50 ;
%let samplesize= 100 ;

data want;
  set have nobs=nobs ;
  array x &varlist ;
  retain _count &samplesize ;
  retain _left ;
  if _n_=1 then _left=dim(x)*nobs ;
  do i=1 to dim(x);
    if (_count/_left > ranuni(&seed)) then do;
        x(i) = . ;
        _count = _count - 1;
    end;
    _left = _left - 1;
  end;
  drop _left _count i ;
run;
```